# Bokeh glyph line_width scaling

Tags: python, zooming, scaling, bokeh, glyph

So I'm currently trying to plot a categorical heatmap in bokeh. It uses rects of 95% size in bokeh, mimicking a grid. I want to highlight areas using rectangles (quads). Getting it to plot is not the problem:
[Heatmap example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJxEn.png)

However, when zooming in and out, the line widths become a problem:

[Zoomed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEbxB.png)

I've read something concerning 'screen' and 'data' dimensioning, but I can't find how to apply this on glyph borders.

**Workaround solution**

I think I could write my own function that adds 4 lines for each rectangle, since line glyphs are scalable if I'm to believe the docs. That doesn't seem very elegant.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data space units only apply to things like the overall width or height or radius of a glyph. Line widths (e.g. glyph outlines) are always and only in screen units (pixels).

However, is there are reason to allow zooming out at all? It seems nonsensical in the presence of categorical axes. You can prevent zooming and panning of categorical axes by setting the [bounds property of ranges](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/ranges.html#bokeh.models.ranges.FactorRange.bounds).

Comment: It would make sense to me in case the size of my matrix changes. I would like to have the borders always exactly as thick as my gridlines. (e.g. 5% of a cell's size). My figures would probably have some default width and height and as more cells are included, the need to zoom in/out becomes more apparent.

Comment: Bokeh respects glyph order when drawing. So, the only other suggestion I can give if you really must have proportional "borders" is to plot two sets of rects. The first is slightly larger and is the "border" color. The second (which will render on top) should be slightly smaller, centered on the first rects, and be the "interior" color. The units for each should be specified in "data space" (the default for rects anyway) In this configuration the "border" will scale.